confusion about the input values for an LN298N driver
I want to control a dc motor via a LN298N driver. I get the basic setup but I am confused about the values for the input.
Here is my setup:

(the red and black cable connect to a 6V battery)
I want to activate the motor when the button is pressed, for which I have this code:
from machine import Pin
   
input1 = Pin(15, Pin.OUT)
input2 = Pin(14, Pin.OUT)
input1.low()
input2.low()

input1.toggle()

This doesn't work, however, if I toggle input2 then it does; which I really don't get.
My understanding is that input1 and input2 (on the LN298N) can each be activated by supplying a voltage. If one is on and the other off then the current flows one way and vice verse. However, if I do this:
from machine import Pin
   
input1 = Pin(15, Pin.OUT)
input2 = Pin(14, Pin.OUT)
input1.high()
input2.low()

then nothing happens
and if I set both to high
from machine import Pin
   
input1 = Pin(15, Pin.OUT)
input2 = Pin(14, Pin.OUT)
input1.high()
input2.high()

Then the motor is still rotating.
Am I doing something wrong? In summary, my question is:

Why is the motor only moving in one configuration (input1: off, input2: on)?
Why is the motor moving at all when both inputs are activated?


these wires you use for supplying current to your controller module: They look too thin.

However, we don't know to which pins on th L298N (I don't think there's an "N" after the "L"?) you've connected your microcontroller pins, so we can't really help you debug this. Also note that the L298N is a rather horrible H-Bridge chip by modern standards, and very likely a bad choice for what you're doing, but that's a separate issue

You don't seem to connect a logic supply voltage anywhere, nor do you connect grounds between microcontroller and H-Bridge controller board. That must be wrong, because with no shared reference voltage between microcontroller and motor driver, there's no understanding what is "high" and what is "low". So, you must really read the documentation that came with your board. It's not optional. The fact that it sometimes works currently is pure luck, and there's reason to assume it's dangerous to the microcontroller pin.
However, having fixed that, it's unlikely you will have a stable system:

(the red and black cable connect to a 6V battery)

Two things about that:

These cables you're using are much thinner than the motor cables. That means they have higher resistance, and that means they drop significant voltage when current flows through them. In fact, they might really be overtasked with supplying current for a motor! Use cables that are at least as strong as the ones you use to connect to the motor.
Your supply voltage is 6 V. That's too little for the ancient L298H. When you read the datasheet (e.g. the ST one) for the L298N, you'll notice that supply voltage needs to be > VIH + 2.5 V. Your microcontroller probably has 3.3 V high output voltage, and 3.3 V + 2.5 V = 5.8 V, so 6 V is barely OK, but these are batteries with non-zero internal resistance, they drop in voltage as they get discharged, and you have a massive cabling problem as described above, so under load, the device will simply not work correctly.

I suspect you're seeing the effects of 2., caused not only by 1., but primarily by the incorrect choice of an L298N for driving a load at a supply voltage this low.
In all honesty, the solution here is to replace the L298N board with a board that uses a "modern" (read: not 50 years old! The L298N is ancient technology.) H-bridge IC. There's very many of these.
The added benefit (aside from it generally working, unlike an L298N with 6 V battery supply) is that the L298N is just a really bad H-Bridge: the transistors in the chip have a very high "on" resistance, meaning that they burn a lot of power, which has two effects: 1. that power doesn't reach the motor and hence, the motor runs weaker than it should, and 2. that power is converted to heat, which is why your board has this large heat sink attached to the IC. So, by switching to a less ancient H-Bridge IC, you get both benefits, higher power to the motor from the same battery, and cheaper board, because nobody has to pay for the gigantic aluminium heat sink!
Note that you already have such a controller – the DRV… from your previous question. You just need to solder in the pin header contacts, no way around that. Don't be afraid of soldering, it's easy.
